# Detect Door Shape in Floor plan using C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I am working on raster images drawing , so my target is to detect only Door Shapes 
I am using ***Emgu C#*** and applied *Haris Corner* algorithm , with threshold = 50 
and then detect a matrix of corners then calculate the distance between two points to proximate that the two points are start & end of door shape 
**The Problem:**
I can't filter image for best detection like how to remove all texts and noise only keep bold walls 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
var img = imgList["Input"].Clone();            
                var gray = img.Convert<Gray, byte>().ThresholdBinaryInv(new Gray(100), new Gray(100)); ;
                imageBoxEx2.Image = gray.ToBitmap();
                var corners = new Mat();
                CvInvoke.CornerHarris(gray, corners,2);
                CvInvoke.Normalize(corners, corners, 255, 0, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.NormType.MinMax);
                Matrix<float> matrix = new Matrix<float>(corners.Rows, corners.Cols);
                corners.CopyTo(matrix);
                dt.Rows.Clear();
                List<Point> LstXpoints = new List<Point>();
                List<Point> LstYpoints = new List<Point>();
                List<PointF> LstF = new List<PointF>();
                for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Rows; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.Cols; j++)
                    {
                        if (matrix[i, j] > threshold)
                        {

                            LstXpoints.Add(new Point ( j, i));
                            LstYpoints.Add(new Point(i, j));
                           // CvInvoke.Circle(img, new Point(j, i), 5, new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Hi, could you please include the unmarked, input image? I'll have an experiment.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood Yes i updated post with original image

Comment: Question, sorry: Will the walls always be orthogonal? Meaning only horizontal or vertical?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood i am working in many images so the walls will be horizontal or vertical or mixed , i hope to help me remove noise and other drawing except bold lines (walls ), to work no walls this will help detect corners and i will predict door shape location

Comment: "Mixed"? I'm asking if you could for example expect a wall of 45 degrees?

Comment: may i misunderstand you but i try to remove all drawing except walls or you have other idea ?

Comment: I understand that, I shall try to ask my question again. In the example you have given, all of the walls are either horizontal, or vertical (left to right, or top to bottom). Are all of the drawings like this? Or do sometimes the walls go at usual angles? Like diagonal?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood ohh, got you Yes, all drawing like in the above image

Comment: Okay great :) Then I have some ideas. Let me some time to work on it and I will get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the python code. But perhaps this will help solve your problem.
See comments.

```
import cv2 

img = cv2.imread('NHoXn.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# convert to binary image
thresh=cv2.threshold(gray, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )[1]

#  Morphological reconstruction (delete labels)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7,7))
kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
marker = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations = 1)
while True:
    tmp=marker.copy()
    marker=cv2.erode(marker, kernel2)
    marker=cv2.max(thresh, marker)
    difference = cv2.subtract(tmp, marker)
    if cv2.countNonZero(difference) == 0:
        break


# only walls
se=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4,4))
walls=cv2.morphologyEx(marker, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, se)
walls=cv2.erode(walls, kernel2,iterations=2)

# other objects
other=cv2.compare(marker,walls, cv2.CMP_GE)
other=cv2.bitwise_not(other)

# find connected components and select by size and area
output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(other, 4, cv2.CV_32S)
num_labels = output[0]
labels = output[1]
stats=output[2]
centroids = output[3]
for i in range(num_labels):
    left,top,width,height,area=stats[i]
    if abs(width-40)<12 and abs(height-40)<12 and area>85:
         cv2.rectangle(img,(left, top), (left+width, top+height), (0,255,0))

cv2.imwrite('doors.png', img)
```

Result:
[image]

1. What is shown in the drawing: walls, doors, windows, furniture, text labels.
2. The doors to be found always touch the walls.
3. How are walls different from other objects? Thick, these lines are bold. Thus, dilatation with the desired structural element can leave only parts of the walls. And then, by morphological reconstruction, restore the walls together with the elements that concern them: doors, windows in the first place. The drawing will be cleaned of everything that does not touch the walls.
4. If dilatation and then erosion are further done, then only walls will remain, thin elements, like windows and doors will disappear.
5. Subtracting (or logical operations) from the third stage the fourth we get a picture that contains only doors, windows and furniture that touched the walls.
6. What is the difference in the drawing of the door from the windows? The fact that their BB is almost square, the size is approximately the same for all doors in this drawing, their length is approximately equal to r*(1+pi/4).
   Further in the code there is a selection for such signs. At this stage, you can add some more signs that will more accurately separate the doors from other elements.

Comment: Hi, Alex i tried code with current image it's works but no work with others please try this image : https://imgur.com/a/09xHZwC

Comment: https://www.upload.ee/files/11862011/select_doors.py.html
To work on this type of drawing, you need to configure the parameters. Unfortunately, 2 false door choices are obtained.
It is necessary to adjust and supplement the selection conditions, except for the size and area, for example, the area of the convex hull or something else.

Comment: @AlexAlex Hello. I'm really interested in your approach, it looks elegant (bravo), but the morphological operations are new to me. Would you kindly expand on the commenting/explanation? Or perhaps cite/reference the relevant documentation. Thank you.

Comment: @george-kerwood Hello. Thank you. I will try to explain. English is not my native language, so please be kind to my mistakes.  Mathematical morphology, I think, is well explained in the writings and books of Luc Vincent. 
Mathematical morphology and its applications to image and signal processing
John Goutsias, Luc M. Vincent, Dan S. Bloomberg

Comment: @AlexAlex Great explanation in perfect English! I see that your algorithm, like mine, will also be susceptible to false detections on any other structure that is "door size" or has a "door-like" BB. To your final point in 6, I think if you were add a final validation, that your detected BBs coincide/touch a wall vertex/corner, this would be a perfect solution. IsaacBe If you are still following this thread, I would recommend this solution over my own. It is far more elegant.

Comment: Thanks google translator for  my English. :-)
Checking if the BB touches the tops of the corners will help only for the first picture, but there may be errors for the second. I thought about it. It's easy to do this in GNU Octave/Matlab (see function bwmorph with 'endpoints' option), in Python it is more difficult for me. 
If you find the skeleton of the walls and find points in it that have only one neighbor, these will be the possible places for fastening the doors.
I believe that the more universal property of door images is their curvature. I should still think about this.

Comment: Changed the script, now in the second picture the doors stand out seem to be without misses. Added two Sobel filters and their logical AND. Script and result in archive:
https://www.upload.ee/files/11891812/door_select.zip.html

Comment: @AlexAlex  thanks for your great solution , i tired it it's worked very good ,but my research in C# development & Emgu , can you guide  me to convert it to c#

Comment: @Isaac Be, sorry, but I can’t help you, because I don’t know the C# programming language...

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood i found a method for calling Python code inside the c# environment, but i guess this need more prerequisites to work rightly  can you help me  converting python code to c# , or what do you think?.. thank you

Comment: @AlexAlex i have other floor plan case , if you have time can you take a look ?

Comment: @Isaac Be, share you other floor plan.

Comment: @AlexAlex in my research not required to recognize all doors if found some but is true door that very good . i tired more to change algorithm to get best results but these has no results  samples in link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KXl8_z1pqof3jThCmoKcKswYN-8hdCWv?usp=sharing  , thank you for your great hep

Answer (score 3):

**[ EDIT - Fully extended answer to provide complete solution ]**

### Preface

I wouldn't usually work to provide a "solution" since I feel it is well beyond a useful, reusable Q&A format... but it was an interesting problem.

### Answer

The following details a base algorithm to detect **potential** door openings within the floor plan. It is not performance optimized or tested beyond the single case provided. Since the definition of a door has been given by OP only as "an opening of specified width", it is also susceptible to false indications. The algorithm can only detect principle, orthogonal doors.

**Example Result:**

[image: Example Result]

### Approach

The approach is as follows:

1. Invert and threshold in the input image, so that the darkest element are cast to white (full byte value).
2. Compute a contour detection, to identify the boundaries of the now white areas.
3. Filter to only select contours on an area greater that a selected threshold (thus removing text elements an noise).
4. "Walk" the selected contours to determine the nodes at which a "corner" occurs. A corner is defined as an angular change above a threshold.
5. Analyse the detected corners for pairings that qualify as "doors".
6. [Superfluous Rendering] Finally, raster within the rectangular bounds for the filtered contours, in order to white fill them into a resultant image. (**Note:** This isn't computational efficient or elegant, however the EmguCV methods for contour filling only support convex contours). The "doors" are also rendered in red.

### Algorithm

```
// Open the image
Image<Gray, byte> baseImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(@"TestLayout.jpg");
// Invert the image
Image<Gray, byte> invBaseImage = baseImage.Not();
// Threshold the image so as "close to white" is maintained, all else is black
Image<Gray, byte> blackOnlyImage = invBaseImage.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(200), new Gray(255));
// An output image of the same size to contain the walls
Image<Gray, byte> wallsOnlyImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(blackOnlyImage.Size);

// A set of dected contours
VectorOfVectorOfPoint inputContours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
// A set of validated contours
List<VectorOfPoint> validContours = new List<VectorOfPoint>();
// Perform contour detection
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
CvInvoke.FindContours(blackOnlyImage, inputContours, hierarchy, RetrType.External, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

// Filter out to select only contours bounding more that 500 pixels
int areaThreshold = 500;
for (int c = 0; c < inputContours.Size; c++)
{ 
    if (CvInvoke.ContourArea(inputContours[c]) >= areaThreshold)
    {
        validContours.Add(inputContours[c]);
    }
}

// Find all the corner points in the valid contours
List<Point> contourCorners = new List<Point>();
foreach(VectorOfPoint contour in validContours)
{
    contourCorners.AddRange(CornerWalk(contour, 80));
}

// Sort the contour corners by proximity to origin in order to optimise following loops
contourCorners.OrderBy(p => Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p.X, 2) + Math.Pow(p.Y, 2)));

// Extract all door candidate point pairs from all detected corners
List<Tuple<Point, Point>> doorCandidates = FindDoors(contourCorners, 2, 30, 45);

// Pixels contained within the filtered contours are walls, fill them white
RasterFill(wallsOnlyImage, validContours);

// Output Image
Image<Rgb, byte> outputImage = new Image<Rgb, byte>(wallsOnlyImage.Size);
CvInvoke.CvtColor(wallsOnlyImage, outputImage, ColorConversion.Gray2Rgb);
// Draw the doors
foreach (Tuple<Point,Point> door in doorCandidates)
{
    outputImage.Draw(new LineSegment2D(door.Item1, door.Item2), new Rgb(255,0,0), 1);
}

// Display generated output and save it to file
CvInvoke.NamedWindow("TestOutput");
CvInvoke.Imshow("TestOutput", outputImage);           
CvInvoke.WaitKey();
outputImage.Save(@"OutputImage.bmp");
```

### Corner Extraction

```
static List<Point> CornerWalk(VectorOfPoint contour, int threshold)
{
    // Create a resultant list of points
    List<Point> result = new List<Point>();

    // Points are used to store 2D vectors as dx,dy (i,j)
    Point reverseVector, forwardVector;
    double theta;
    // For each point on the contour
    for(int p = 1; p < contour.Size; p++)
    {
        // Determine the vector to the prior point
        reverseVector = new Point()
        {
            X = contour[p].X - contour[p - 1].X,
            Y = contour[p].Y - contour[p - 1].Y,
        };

        // Determine the vector to the next point
        forwardVector = p == contour.Size - 1 ?
        new Point()
        {
            X = contour[0].X - contour[p].X,
            Y = contour[0].Y - contour[p].Y,
        } :
        new Point()
        {
            X = contour[p + 1].X - contour[p].X,
            Y = contour[p + 1].Y - contour[p].Y,
        };

        // Compute the angular delta between the two vectors (Radians)
        theta = Math.Acos(((reverseVector.X * forwardVector.X) + (reverseVector.Y * forwardVector.Y)) /
            (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(reverseVector.X, 2) + Math.Pow(reverseVector.Y, 2)) *
            Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(forwardVector.X, 2) + Math.Pow(forwardVector.Y, 2))));

        // Convert the angle to degrees
        theta *= 180 / Math.PI;

        // If the angle is above or equal the threshold, the point is a corner
        if (theta >= threshold) result.Add(contour[p]);
    }

    // Return the result
    return result;
}
```

### Door Detection

```
static List<Tuple<Point, Point>> FindDoors(
    List<Point> cornerPoints,
    int inLineTolerance,
    int minDoorWidth,
    int maxDoorWidth)
{
    // Create a resultant list of pairs of points
    List<Tuple<Point, Point>> results = new List<Tuple<Point, Point>>();
    Point p1, p2;
    // For every point in the list
    for (int a = 0; a < cornerPoints.Count; a++)
    {
        p1 = cornerPoints[a];
        // Against every other point in the list
        for (int b = 0; b < cornerPoints.Count; b++)
        {
            // Don't compare a point to it's self...
            if (a == b) continue;
            p2 = cornerPoints[b];

            // If p1 to p2 qualifies as a door:
                // Vertical Doors -     A vertical door will have to points of the same X value, within tolerance, and a Y value delta within the
                //                      min-max limits of a door width.
            if (((Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X) < inLineTolerance) && (Math.Abs(p1.Y - p2.Y) > minDoorWidth) && (Math.Abs(p1.Y - p2.Y) < maxDoorWidth)) ||
                // Horizontal Doors -   A horizontal door will have to points of the same Y value, within tolerance, and a X value delta within the
                //                      min-max limits of a door width.
                ((Math.Abs(p1.Y - p2.Y) < inLineTolerance) && (Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X) > minDoorWidth) && (Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X) < maxDoorWidth)))
            {
                // Add the point pair to the result
                results.Add(new Tuple<Point, Point>(p1, p2));
                // Remove them from further consideration
                cornerPoints.Remove(p1);
                cornerPoints.Remove(p2);
                // Decrement the looping indexes and start over with a new p1
                b--; a--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Finally return the result
    return results;
}
```

### Contour Filling (Render Utility - Not Functional)

```
static void RasterFill(Image<Gray,byte> dstImg, List<VectorOfPoint> contours)
{
    Rectangle contourBounds;
    PointF testPoint;
    // For each contour detected
    foreach(VectorOfPoint contour in contours)
    {
        // Within the bounds of this contour
        contourBounds = CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(contour);
        for (int u = contourBounds.X; u < contourBounds.X + contourBounds.Width; u++)
        {
            for (int v = contourBounds.Y; v < contourBounds.Y + contourBounds.Height; v++)
            {
                // Test to determine whether the point is within the contour
                testPoint = new PointF(u, v);
                // If it is inside the contour, OR on the contour
                if (CvInvoke.PointPolygonTest(contour, testPoint, false) >= 0)
                {
                    // Set it white
                    dstImg.Data[v, u, 0] = 255;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Did it work for you? Kindly mark the question answered if so.

Comment: Still trying to predict doors locations , so  i try to get ends for each wall , Have an idea to get only ends points for each wall ? thank you

Comment: How to mathematically define a door? How do you expect to differentiate between doors and windows for example?

Comment: Only now detecting door by getting the distance between two points if equals lets say between 35 and 55 this is should be a hole for door . that's all so i am working to detect only ends points for each wall.

Comment: Well I can do this easy enough: https://imgur.com/mUb4C9p. But it's not perfect. You get "double doors" and some erroneous results. What is this for if I may ask? Studies? An industrial application?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/6796061/george-kerwood Rresearch  project , okay this good solution , and i will enhance it ,in future

Comment: @IsaacBe Bold to suggest you'll enhance it when you've struggled with the first stage, but never the less, here's your "research" :)

Comment: i didn't got you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215696/discussion-between-george-kerwood-and-isaac-be).